# How to Exclude Devextreme from ngx-build-plus from prod build Angular?

Tags: angular, webpack, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I have been using devextreme in angular application, but while making prod build its taking more size. So, I wanted to exclude it from prod build using ngx-build-plus and webpack ignore plugin but its not excluding.

1. I tried with ngx-build-plus with webpack.extras.js, it does not exclude.

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     "externals": {
       "rxjs": "rxjs",
       "@angular/core": "ng.core",
       "@angular/common": "ng.common",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "ng.platformBrowser",
       "devextreme" : "devextreme",
       "devexpress-diagram": "devexpress-diagram",
       "devextreme-schematics": "devextreme-schematics",
       "devextreme-angular": "devextreme-angular",
     }
   }
   ```
2. I tried with webpack ignore plugin to exclude it, I see error not matching api scheme.

   > An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. - configuration.externals['plugins'][0] should be a string.

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     "externals": {
       "rxjs": "rxjs",
       "@angular/core": "ng.core",
       "@angular/common": "ng.common",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "ng.platformBrowser",
       "plugins":[
         new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/devextreme/)
       ]
     }
   }
   ```

It should exclude devextreme from the `prod` build. Please let me know if any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You placed your `plugins` configuration object inside your `externals` configuration object. It should be:

```js
module.exports = {
  "externals": {
    "rxjs": "rxjs",
    "@angular/core": "ng.core",
    "@angular/common": "ng.common",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "ng.platformBrowser"
  },
  "plugins":[
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/devextreme/)
  ]
}
```